# GeoPandas: assigning unique colors and labels to entries

Tags: python, geopandas, plot

I would like to plot a map with colors that depend on a categorical variable, i.e. a column with integer number labels (0, 1, 2, ..., 10 for example). Using `gdf.plot(column=categorical_variable)` I am able to plot different shapes with different colors. Also, by using replacing the `categorical_variable` column with the colors I would like to represent them with, I can then issue the `gdf.plot(color=colors_associated_to_categorical_variable)` and plot the shapes in the desired color. However, in the latter case the legend does not show up, since labels from the categorical variable are missing.

How can I achieve both *color customization* **and** *polygon labelling*?